# Java Jpanel setBounds not working

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, layout-manager

I encountered a wierd problem in a JFrame cointaining 2 JPanels.
I got a class called "SlotCheck" which extends JFrame.
and i got a Class called "Slot" which Extends JPanel.
In the SlotCheck constructor i add 2 Slot instances called sl and s2.
I use setBounds() to put them in two diffrent locations on the board.

sl.setBounds works and puts it where i indicate.
but s2.setBounds doesnt work and it puts it in (0,0).

here is how it looks:

[image]

i would love to know why it does that.

here is the SlotCheck class:

```
package Try1;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SlotCheck extends JFrame{
  private Slot sl;
  private Slot s2;
  public SlotCheck() throws IOException{
  sl = new Slot(4,2,SlotType.white);
  System.out.print(sl.toString());
  add(sl);
  sl.setBounds(100,0,40,300);
  sl.setVisible(true);

  s2 = new Slot(6,2,SlotType.black);
  System.out.print(s2.toString());
  add(s2);
  s2.setBounds(200,0,40,300);
  s2.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
  SlotCheck sc = new SlotCheck();
  sc.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  sc.setTitle("check of slot");
  sc.setVisible(true);
  sc.setLocation(300, 200);
  sc.setSize(400,400);
  }
}
```

And here is the Slot class:

It is kind of long but i hope you will understand. 
Also the paintComponent class is down in the code and i think its the one that matters so u can go there.

```
  package Try1;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

// slot is a defined place on the backgammon board that can hold 
// one type of pieces black or white.
//there are 24 slots 12 on each side and 6 in each quartor.
//if a slot holds 2 or more pieces those pieces cannot be eaten.
public class Slot extends JPanel{
  private int slotNumber;
  private int piecesAmount;
  private SlotType type;
  private Stack<WhitePiece> wPieces;
  private Stack<BlackPiece> bPieces;
  private Image wPieceImage;
  private Image bPieceImage;
  public Slot() throws IOException{
  type = SlotType.empty;
  piecesAmount = 0;
  setSize(300,40);
  wPieces = new Stack<WhitePiece>();
  bPieces = new Stack<BlackPiece>();
  wPieceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/whitePiece.png"));
  bPieceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/blackPiece.png"));
 }
  public Slot(int pA, int sN, SlotType t) throws IOException{
  if(t != SlotType.empty){
      piecesAmount = pA;
      slotNumber = sN;
      type = t;
      wPieces = new Stack<WhitePiece>();
      bPieces = new Stack<BlackPiece>();
      wPieceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/whitePiece.png"));
      bPieceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/blackPiece.png"));
      if(t == SlotType.black){
          for(int i=0;i<pA;i++)
              bPieces.push(new BlackPiece());
      }else{
          for(int i=0;i<pA;i++)
              wPieces.push(new WhitePiece());
      }
  }
  }
  public SlotType getType(){
  return type;
  }
  public void setType(SlotType t){
  if(piecesAmount == 0)
    type = t;
  }
   public int getPiecesAmount(){
  return piecesAmount;
  }
   public void setPiecesAmount(int pa) throws IOException{ 
  if(type != SlotType.empty){
      piecesAmount = pa;
      if(type == SlotType.black){
         if(pa>bPieces.size())
           for(int i=0;i<(pa-bPieces.size());i++)
              bPieces.push(new BlackPiece());
         else
             if(pa<bPieces.size())
                 for(int i=0;i<(bPieces.size()-pa);i++)
                     bPieces.pop();
     }
      else{
          if(pa>wPieces.size())
               for(int i=0;i<(pa-wPieces.size());i++)
                  wPieces.push(new WhitePiece());
             else
                 if(pa<wPieces.size())
                     for(int i=0;i<(wPieces.size()-pa);i++)
                         wPieces.pop();
      }
  }else{
      System.out.println("Slot #"+slotNumber+" is Empty Slot");
  }
  }
  public void decreasePiecesAmount(){
  if(type != SlotType.empty){
      piecesAmount --;
      if(type == SlotType.black)
          bPieces.pop();
      else
          wPieces.pop();
  }
  }
  public void increasePiecesAmount() throws IOException{
  if(type != SlotType.empty){
      piecesAmount ++;
      if(type == SlotType.black)
          bPieces.push(new BlackPiece());
      else
          wPieces.push(new WhitePiece());
  }
  }
  public void pushPiece(){

  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
  if(type == SlotType.empty){ 
      System.out.println("no type selected slot is empty Slot  Number"+slotNumber);
  }else
      if(type == SlotType.white){
        if(!wPieces.isEmpty()){
        try {
            wPieces.push(new WhitePiece());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(slotNumber <= 11){
          for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
            g.drawImage( wPieceImage, 5, i*30, null);
          }
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
                g.drawImage(wPieceImage, 5,300-(i*30), null);
            }
       }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Slot Stack is Empty Slot #"+slotNumber);
        }
      }else
      {
          if(!bPieces.isEmpty()){

          if(slotNumber<=11){
             for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
                g.drawImage(bPieceImage, 5, i*30, 30, 30, null);
            }
          }else{
              for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
                    g.drawImage(bPieceImage, 5, 300-(i*30), 30, 30, null);
              }  
          }
    }
          else{
      System.out.println("Slot Stack is empty Slot #"+slotNumber);
   }
}

}
protected void setSlotNumber(int sN){
  slotNumber = sN;
}
public int getSlotNumber(){
  return slotNumber;
}
public String toString(){
return "Slot #"+slotNumber+"\nSlot Type is: "+type.toString()+"\nAmount of pieces is: "+piecesAmount;
  }

}
```

I appritiate your help.

Comment: In addition to the advice already given by Hovercraft, be sure to do all GUI tasks in the event dispatch thread. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `setBounds(...)` only works for null layouts.
- But having said that, don't use null layouts!
- Don't use `setBounds(...)`
- Learn about the Swing layout managers and let them do the heavy lifting of laying components for you. The tutorial link is: [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);` inside of your paintComponent method, usually on the first line of the override.

Comment: i cant see the link
ok now i can
but what if i want to decide where it is exactly?

Comment: yeah it is visible now.
but in my case i want to decide where the Slot is precisly.
because later i will have to adjust it on an image.

Comment: Sure there's valid use for `setBounds()` - when writing a layout manager.

Comment: @kiheru: OK, will grant you that.

Comment: @GiladBenYe: if you need more specific help on laying stuff out, consider posting images and an [sscce](http://sscce.org). With this information we can give much better advice quicker. Luck!

Comment: @GiladBenYe: please click on the link.

Answer (score -1):

ok i found the problem.
i didnt put setLayout(null);

Comment: That works, but it is *really* better to use layout managers. Otherwise you will need to do all the positioning manually, including handling resizes etc. At which point you could just as well write a layout manager. But almost always there's something that fits the situation, considering that you can use nested layouts.

Comment: ok i will learn that 
but for now my program is small and it is easier for me to 
use no layout manager then starting to learn layout managers.

Comment: @GiladBenYe: you are falling into a common trap -- it's easier in the short term to use null layout, but it is much more difficult in the long term. I strongly urge you not to do this, not to use null layouts as they will bite you in the butt. Imagine creating a complex GUI and then later realizing that you need to add one more JRadioButton to the middle of the GUI. With null layout, you have to manually shift *everything* to fit in the new component and resize the complete GUI, all with risk of bugs. With layout managers, you just add *one line* of code, that's it.

Comment: first of all thank you for the caring.
i understand it is not good in the long term but for now.
i just need my simpel game to work.
after i get it to work i will improve it in many ways.

Comment: Except there are situations when using null layouts makes sense. For instance, I'm using swing to render card graphics to a custom JComponent by overwriting the paint method. Now, for this I have to do custom position calculation *anyway*, so I might as well reuse that for the other subcomponents of my card rendering component. This is just a use case where using a null layout is the simplest choice, and I really don't appreciate finding this Q&A and then seeing lots of "don't use null layout" rather than an answer to the question asked.